# electron-forge, how to create setup.exe so that it will be installed for all users on a machine

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

using `electron-forge`, my forge.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
    icon: 'icon.ico',
    perMachine: true,
    installScope: 'perMachine',
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
      config: {
        setupIcon: 'icon.ico',
        name: "myapp",
        setupType: "dir",
        setupExe: "myapp.exe",
        perMachine: true,
        installScope: 'perMachine',
      },
    },
```

but when i run `npm run make` it still gets installed in `%AppData\Local%
i want my unstallation to be shared across all users on windows, how?

expecting my app to be installed on all windows users, tried the configs inside forge.config.js and running app with admin